# Error: "uninitialized constant Object::Rack" when using gem rack-throttle in ruby Volt framework

Tags: ruby, voltrb

I am trying to throttle malicious from my website by using [rack-throttle](https://github.com/bendiken/rack-throttle) in the new [Volt framework](http://voltframework.com/). Here is my code in the compnent/config/initializers/boot.rb file:

```
Volt.current_app.middleware.use(Rack::Throttle::Minute, max: 60)
```

Limiting the requests per minute works correctly, but I am getting an error message that says the following:

```
Uncaught NameError: uninitialized constant Object::Rack
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you require 'rack/throttle' first?

Also, for middleware, you want to be sure its only running on the server:

```
unless RUBY_PLATFORM == 'opal'
  Volt.current_app.middleware.use(Rack::Throttle::Minute, max: 60)
end
```

Comment: The problem was that I was running it on both the client and the server. "unless RUBY_PLATFORM == 'opal'" fixed this error. Thank you.